# Rails partials and passing in instance var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rendering, partials

I have a partial (_car_grid.html.erb) as follows:

```
<ul class="car-grid">
  <%= render @cars %>
</ul>
```

Then I wish to call the partial from elsewhere but the instance var I am using is called `@car_results`. Is there a way to pass in `@car_results` and have it act as `@cars` inside the partial?

I have tried:

```
<%= render 'shared/car_grid', locals: {cars: @car_results} %>
```

But it doesn't seem to like it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  Drop the '@' in your partial so that `@cars` becomes `cars`.  When you pass in locals to a partial the partial receives local variables, not instance variables.

This means you'll need to change your other invocation of the partial as well to this:

```
<%= render 'shared/car_grid', locals: {cars: @cars} %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I do that the `render cars` line fails so I updated it to   <ul class="car-grid">
  <% cars.each do |car| %>
    <%= render 'cars/car' %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

But this fails with undefined local variable or method `cars'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Odd.  Step through it bit by bit until you see where it's losing your variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your partial, do not use the instance variable. Philip's suggestion is correct.

However, another thing I noticed in your code is that you are using the wrong syntax for rendering the partial. Actually, there are two ways for rendering partial

```
<%= render partial: "shared/car_grid", locals: {cars: @car_results} %>
```

or

```
<%= render "shared/car_grid", cars: @car_results %>
```

Your code does not contain `partial` keywords, so you will not need to use `locals`

Answer (score 0):

**Partials**

By their nature, Rails [`partials`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) are not meant to take `@instance variables`. They are meant to be used in any part of your application, hence why you need to pass `local variables` to them:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/car_grid', locals: { cars: @car_results } %>
```

A partial is essentially like a `code block` - where `local` variables are referenced. This means inside the partial, you'll have to call a local variable, as defined when calling the partial:

```
#app/views/shared/_car_grid.html.erb
<% cars.each do |car| %>
    <%= car.name %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Collections**

Some other interesting functionality you should know about is the use of [`collection`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) when calling a partial.

```
<%= render partial: "shared/car_grids", collection: @car_results, as: :car %>
```

This basically works like an `each` loop - giving you the ability to reload the partial again & again for each member of the collection